# Call asmx HTTP POST from android

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services, http

I'm trying to post HTTP from android. If I'll request using that C# code in LINQPAD it works

```
void Main()
{
    string r = String.Format(@"<s:Body><TrackMobileApp xmlns=""soap action url"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><device>test</device><imei>test</imei><ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress><timeStamp>2016-02-17T17:32:00.5147663+04:00</timeStamp></TrackMobileApp></s:Body>", DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));

    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL.asmx");
    wr.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    wr.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "soap action");
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wr.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        sw.Write(r);
    } 
    HttpWebResponse rs = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
    if (rs.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            xd.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
            xd.InnerXml.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

But from android it gives me http 415. What's wrong?

I have this in `onCreate`

```
new DownloadTask().execute("URL.asmx");
```

and my methods are:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do your request in here so that you don't interrupt the UI thread
        try {
            return downloadContent(params[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Here you are done with the task
    }
}

private String downloadContent(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    int length = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "soap action");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = convertInputStreamToString(is, length);
        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream stream, int length) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[length];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: You are using two different values for Content-Type, perhaps that's a problem?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE If I'll make `text/xml;charset=utf-8` as content type then it's http 400

Comment: That's unfortunate. I also see that you are writing a String as content in C# and your not doing that for Android. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE that string is response which I'm expecting from android (i'm retrieving IMEI code and ip etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix your issue, but as you are doing a POST request, you might need to add `conn.setDoOutput(true)`